# sumifs formula that sums the first 100 records only and multiplies by a number and then the next 100 by different number

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I modify this formula to include summing only the first 100 records and then multiply by a number? And then another formula that will sum the next 100 records and multiply by a difference number? and so on

=SUM(SUMIFS(GalleyDet_NotMailed,GalleyDet_Month,$C$4,GalleyDet_UBR,C$39))*0.33781

Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of the Sum() function wrapped around the Sumifs()??

Comment: Better use helper column with COUNT rows and then use SUMIF with required criteria including IF ROW COUNT <=100,,, and others .